# How to construct a loop with reducing iterations

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, image-processing

In MATLAB, I have a 256x256 RGB image and a 3x3 kernel that passes over it. The 3x3 kernel computes the colour-euclidean distance between every pair combination of the 9 pixels in the kernel, and stores the maximum value in an array. It then moves by 1 pixel and performs the same computation, and so on.

I can easily code the movement of the kernel over the image, as well as the extraction of the RGB values from the pixels in the kernel.

HOWEVER, I do have trouble efficiently computing the colour-euclidean distance operation for every pair combination of pixels.

For example if I had a 3x3 matrix with the following values:

[55 12 5; 77 15 99; 124 87 2]

I need to code a loop such that the 1st element performs an operation with the 2nd,3rd...9th element. Then the 2nd element performs the operation with the 3rd,4th...9th element and so on until finally the 8th element performs the operation with the 9th element. Preferrably, the same pixel combination shouldn't compute again (like if you computed 2nd with 7th, don't compute 7th with 2nd).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: My code so far

```
K=3;
s=1; %If S=0, don't reject, If S=1 Reject first max distance pixel pair
OI=imread('onion.png');
Rch = im2col(OI(:,:,1),[K,K],'sliding')
Gch = im2col(OI(:,:,2),[K,K],'sliding')
Bch = im2col(OI(:,:,3),[K,K],'sliding')

indexes = bsxfun(@gt,(1:K^2)',1:K^2)
a=find(indexes);
[idx1,idx2] = find(indexes);

Rsqdiff = (Rch(idx2,:) - Rch(idx1,:)).^2
Gsqdiff = (Gch(idx2,:) - Gch(idx1,:)).^2
Bsqdiff = (Bch(idx2,:) - Bch(idx1,:)).^2

dists = sqrt(double(Rsqdiff + Gsqdiff + Bsqdiff))                           %Distance values for all 36 combinations in 1 column
[maxdist,idx3] = max(dists,[],1)                                            %idx3 is each column's index of max value

if s==0
    y = reshape(maxdist,size(OI,1)-K+1,[])                                  %max value of each column (each column has 36 values)
elseif s==1
    [~,I]=max(maxdist);
    idx3=idx3(I);
    n=size(idx3,2);
    for i=1:1:n
        idx3(i)=a(idx3(i));
    end
    [I,J]=ind2sub([K*K K*K],idx3);
    for j=1:1:a
        [M,N]=ind2sub([K*K K*K],dists(j,:));
        M(I,:)=0;
        N(:,J)=0;
        dists(j,:)=sub2ind; %Incomplete line, don't know what to do here
    end
    [maxdist,idx3] = max(dists,[],1);
    y = reshape(maxdist,size(OI,1)-K+1,[]);
end
```

Comment: What about a 2 pass filtering? First a pass to calculate the distance for each pixel, the a pass to take the maximum.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm a novice coder. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please add the code you already got to your question.

Comment: Done. Bear in mind that the code is basic and feel free to restructure it completely.

Comment: What would be the size of output array for `256x256` image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking to form unique pairwise combinations within a sliding `3x3` window, perform euclidean distance calculations consider all three channels, which we are calling as *colour-euclidean distances* and finally picking out the largest of all distances for each sliding window. So, for a `3x3` window that has `9` elements, you would have `36` unique pairs.  If the image size is `MxN`, because of the sliding nature, you would have `(M-3+1)*(N-3+1)` = `64516` (for `256x256` case) such sliding windows with 36 pairs each, and therefore the distances array would be `36x64516` sized and the output array of maximum distances would be of size `254x254`. The implementation suggested here involves [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to extract sliding windowed elements as columns, [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) to form the pairs and finally performing the square-root of squared differences between three channels of such pairs and would look something like this -

```
K = 3; %// Kernel size
Rch = im2col(img(:,:,1),[K,K],'sliding')
Gch = im2col(img(:,:,2),[K,K],'sliding')
Bch = im2col(img(:,:,3),[K,K],'sliding')

[idx1,idx2] = find(bsxfun(@gt,(1:K^2)',1:K^2)); %//'

Rsqdiff = (Rch(idx2,:) - Rch(idx1,:)).^2
Gsqdiff = (Gch(idx2,:) - Gch(idx1,:)).^2
Bsqdiff = (Bch(idx2,:) - Bch(idx1,:)).^2

dists = sqrt(Rsqdiff + Gsqdiff + Bsqdiff)
out = reshape(max(dists,[],1),size(img,1)-K+1,[])
```

Comment: you could have done the `sqrt` operation after the `max` one!

Comment: @smlq Ah yes, that's one minor optimization, thanks!

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Sorry if I didn't frame my question appropriately, but you seem to have understood it anyway!

Comment: @user3749634 No worries, but I guess in future with your questions you can improve on it :)

Comment: My next step is to reject the maximum distance of each column in dists (also reject the pixel pair which created the maximum), and then find the next maximum in each column, which results from two different pixels. I've entered the code which I have in the main post.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting and caught my attention. As far as I understood, you need to calculate euclidean distance between RGB color values of all cells inside 3x3 kernel and to find the largest one. I suggest a possible way to do this by using `circshift` function and 4D array operations:

Firstly, we pad the input array and create 8 shifted versions of it for each direction:

```
DIM = 256;
A = zeros(DIM,DIM,3,9);
A(:,:,:,1) = round(255*rand(DIM,DIM,3));%// random 256x256 array (suppose it is your image)
A = padarray(A,[1,1]);%// add zeros on each side of image
%// compute shifted versions of the input array
%// and write them as 4th dimension starting from shifted up clockwise:
A(:,:,:,2) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[-1, 0]);
A(:,:,:,3) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[-1, 1]);
A(:,:,:,4) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[ 0, 1]);
A(:,:,:,5) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[ 1, 1]);
A(:,:,:,6) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[ 1, 0]);
A(:,:,:,7) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[ 1,-1]);
A(:,:,:,8) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[ 0,-1]);
A(:,:,:,9) = circshift(A(:,:,:,1),[-1,-1]);
```

Next, we create an array that calculates the difference for all the possible combinations between all the above arrays:

```
q = nchoosek(1:9,2);
B = zeros(DIM+2,DIM+2,3,size(q,1));
for i = 1:size(q,1)
    B(:,:,:,i) = (A(:,:,:,q(i,1)) - A(:,:,:,q(i,2))).^2;
end
C = sqrt(sum(B,3));
```

Finally, what we have is all the euclidean distances between all possible pairs within a 3x3 kernel. All we have to do is to extract the maximum values. As far as I understood, you do not consider image edges, so:

```
C = sqrt(sum(B,3));
D = zeros(DIM-2);
for i = 3:DIM
    for j = 3:DIM
        temp = C(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);
        D(i-2,j-2) = max(temp(:));
    end
end
```

`D` is the 254x254 array with maximum Euclidean distances for A(2:255,2:255), i.e. we exclude image edges.

Hope that helps.

P.S. I am amazed by the shortness of the code provided by @Divakar.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate how you explained every step you did, it helped clear some doubts about the logic that I had.